# How can I install Debian Jessie on a Lenovo Thinkpad T450s via a USB stick?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, debian, thinkpad

I just bought a Lenovo Thinkpad T450s with Windows 7 pre-installed. I'd like to install Debian Jessie. I obtained an .iso file [here](https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst) (I selected `amd64` from the Small CDs or USB sticks section). After that, I formatted a 2.0 GB USB stick to FAT and then ran the following commands:

```
cp debian.iso /dev/sdf1
sync
```

That should do it, according to [this webpage](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/amd64/ch04s03.html.en#idp5907872). I then made sure I copied the .iso to the correct device. After that, when booting my laptop, I made sure `Secure Boot` was set to `[Disabled]` and I enabled `Legacy` boot. When booting, I press `F12` to opent he tboot menu. In the boot menu I see the following options:

```
ATA HDD0: TOSHIBA THNSFJ256GCSU // This is the 256 GB SSD
USB HDD: Generic Flash Disk     // I assume this is my USB stick
PCI LAN: IBA GE Slot 00C8 v1553 // This is LAN
```

I select `USB HDD: Generic Flash Disk` and the screen goes blank (it appears to work for a second) but then the boot menu reappears.

**Am I somehow incorrectly copying the .iso to the USB stick? Is there *another* setting that I am missing, barring me from booting from the USB stick?**

---

Furthermore, I've also tried this command, when copying the .iso to the USB stick:

```
cat debian.iso > /dev/sdf1; sync
```

But to no avail.

Also, when entering `dmesg` in terminal I get a bunch of errors that look like this:

```
[118143.632226] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 67576
[118143.632229] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 67577
[118143.632233] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 67578
[118143.632236] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 67579
[118143.632239] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 67580
[118143.632242] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 67581
[118143.632246] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 67582
[118143.632249] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 67583
```

Comment: I'd recommend the use of [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) to create bootable USB drive. You can then add any linux iso / distro via YUMI as needed.

Comment: @Darius I'm running Debian on my other machine, so I don't believe I can use YUMI without Wine.

Comment: The new lenovo Windows OS is already gone?

Comment: @Darius No, lol. I forgot about that. I guess I'll try this if there's no other way.

Comment: By the way, why /dev/sdf1? If I read that instruction correctly, it should be just /dev/sdf - and assuming the USB Stick is unmounted. - This is also assuming sdf is where your usb stick is.

Comment: @Darius That's it. I was accidentally writing to the volume instead of the stick itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully, I accidentally wrote to the volume `/dev/sdf1` instead of the stick, itself, `/dev/sdf`. This change allowed me to boot from the stick and install Debian Jessie. Thank you, [Darius](https://superuser.com/users/5032/darius), for pointing this out.

Comment: I not allowed to accept my own answer within 2 days, otherwise I would. @Larssend